# Should this be refactored to be more DRY?

Tags: ruby, refactoring, conditional-statements, dry

I am working through Chris Pine's Chapter 6 Deaf Grandman challenge. It looks very readable however I wonder if this is violating the DRY principle. If so, how can I refactor it?

```
puts "WHAT DID YOU SAY??"
said = gets.chomp
x = 0
bye_counter = 0

while bye_counter < 3
  if said != said.upcase
    puts "HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!"
    said = gets.chomp
    bye_counter = 0

  elsif said == said.upcase && said != "BYE"
    puts "NO, NOT SINCE " + rand(1930..1950).to_s + "!"
    bye_counter  = 0
    said = gets.chomp

  elsif said == "BYE"
    puts "HUH??"
    bye_counter += 1
    break if bye_counter == 3
    said = gets.chomp
  end
end
puts "OH.. OK!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution:

```
message = "WHAT DID YOU SAY??"
bye_counter = 0
puts message

while bye_counter < 3
  said = gets.chomp
  if said == "BYE"
    message = "HUH??"
    bye_counter += 1
  else 
    if said == said.upcase
        message = "NO, NOT SINCE " + rand(1930..1950).to_s + "!"
    else
        message = "HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!"
    end
    bye_counter  = 0
  end
  break if bye_counter == 3
  puts message
end
puts "OH.. OK!"
```